# NLog breaks when using operator '<'

Tags: .net, visual-studio, nlog

I have a configuration below and a relational operator '<' seems to be not escaped because it outputs error `XML element is not closed`. [In documentation](https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/Conditions) they have an example with '<=', which doesn't work too. What's interesting, '>' works fine. Am I missing something?

```
<logger name="*" minlevel="Trace" writeTo="logFile">
  <filters>
    <when condition="contains('${logger}','Domain.Messaging.') and level < LogLevel.Warn" action="Ignore" />
  </filters>
</logger>
```

Comment: Looking at that documentation, the example uses `>=` not `<=`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Am I missing something?

Yup, you're not taking into account that this is XML, where `<` needs to be escaped. You want:

```
<logger name="*" minlevel="Trace" writeTo="logFile">
  <filters>
    <when condition="contains('${logger}','Domain.Messaging.') and level &lt; LogLevel.Warn" action="Ignore" />
  </filters>
</logger>
```

From section 2.4 of the [XML 1.0 specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml/):

> The ampersand character (`&`) and the left angle bracket (`<`) must not appear in their literal form, except when used as markup delimiters, or within a comment, a processing instruction, or a CDATA section. If they are needed elsewhere, they must be escaped using either numeric character references or the strings `&amp;` and `&lt;` respectively.

Comment: You was correct, I got an exception because of typo. Thanks!